# C++ Move constructor won't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, move

I have an unfortunate problem. My GCC 4.6.3 compiler refuses to compile my move constructor. 
Exchanging line 6 in the example with "MemoryBlock(const MemoryBlock & other)" would make it compile, but not using the below move constructor declaration. Seems like the compiler does not know C+11, even though it should using 4.6.3. Right?

```
#include <cstddef>

class MemoryBlock
{
public:
   MemoryBlock(MemoryBlock && other) //<----------- RAD 6.
    {
    }

private:
   size_t _length; // The length of the resource.
   int* _data; // The resource.
};

int main() {

}
```

Compiler output:

> prog.cpp:6:28: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
>
> prog.cpp:6:36: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘MemoryBlock (const MemoryBlock&)’
>
> make: *** [slask] Error 1

GCC version:

> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 (Kör från labbsal i skolan)

makefile:

```
%.out:    %.cpp
    g++ -g -W -Wall -std=c++0x $*.cpp -o $*.out;
```

Comment: Works fine on my GCC 4.6.3. Make sure you're actually using the right version; check directly on the command line without makefile perhaps.

Comment: I did verify my version (g++ --version) and its correct. However, you are right, it works. The problem seem to lie within my makefile. Thanks alot! My makefile seemed so simple that I didn't really consider it an issue. Any idea what could be the problem using this makefile?

Comment: Your makefile may not be using the rule you specified, but the default rule.

Comment: You can greatly simplify the makefile for small code samples by setting `CXXFLAGS` and letting the default rules do their job.

Comment: In fact, the more I look at it, the more it seems that Everything Is Wrong with that makefile. Maybe pick up a Makefile tutorial and work though it slowly, step-by-step. Especially substitution rules and magic variables should be double-checked.

Comment: This code is so against why move semantics exist (think `unique_ptr` or even just `std::vector`)

Answer (score 1):

Try -std=c++11 instead of -std=c++0x.  While your compiler knows the usage, the -std=c++0x "turns off" those new rules.